# Export Data (as CSV) with formatting and Comments

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to Export my Data in Excel with VBA whilst also exporting Cellcomments and ColorFormatting?

I don't quite find a solution to export it that way.

Comment: Short answer: no.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values):

> In computing, a comma-separated values (CSV) file stores tabular data (numbers and text) in **plain text**.

Thus no colors and no comments.

If you want to store them in CSV, you can write code to collect these information from cells and store them as text somewhere in the worksheet (e.g. copy color as hex code).